# Masonry CSS без использования columns

Tags: html, css, masonry

Кто нибудь знает как создать masonry каталог товаров? Делал при помощи columns, но это вариант не подходит, т.к товары в колонку а не в ряд и при сортировке сбивается последовательность

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент реализация masonry-раскладки на CSS невозможна, но работа в этом направлении ведется. Недавно был опубликован черновик спецификации CSS Grid 3 уровня, в котором содержится описание способа создания Masonry-раскладки с помощью чистого CSS.

Используйте [Masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/) или можете попробовать сделать на экспериментальных свойствах.
Подробнее можно почитать здесь: [Нативный Masonry Layout в CSS Grid Level 3](https://habr.com/ru/post/526008/)